# How do you enable a GL function in Qt3D with QML

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt3d

I am writing an application using Qt3D. Most of the 3D handling I have been doing has used QML not the C++ interface. I have created a QML effect that loads my shader programs similar to the PerVertex color effect QML that ships with Qt5.9.

The problem I am having is I am trying to write a fragment shader and utilize `glBlendFunc(sfactor, dfactor)`. According to the OpenGL documentation, I need to set `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and use `glBlendFunc`, but I don't know how to do that using QML. I can see how it is done on the C++ side of things, but as I am using QML Scene3D, that would take a great deal of rewriting to accomplish. Can anyone tell me how to enable OpenGL functions (like `GL_BLEND`) via Qt3D QML?

As requested, the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// TODO: Replace with a struct
uniform vec3 ka;            // Ambient reflectivity
uniform vec3 kd;            // Diffuse reflectivity
uniform vec3 ks;            // Specular reflectivity
uniform float shininess;    // Specular shininess factor
uniform float alpha;

uniform vec3 eyePosition;

in vec3 worldPosition;
in vec3 worldNormal;
in vec3 color;

out vec4 fragColor;

#pragma include light.inc.frag

void main()
{
    vec3 diffuseColor, specularColor;
    adsModel(worldPosition, worldNormal, eyePosition, shininess, diffuseColor, specularColor);
    fragColor = vec4( ka * color + kd * color * diffuseColor + ks * color * specularColor, 1.0 );
}
```

Here is also the Effect component:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0

Effect {
    id: root

parameters: [
    Parameter { name: "k";         value: Qt.vector3d( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 )    },
    Parameter { name: "kd";        value: Qt.vector3d( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7 )    },
    Parameter { name: "ks";        value: Qt.vector3d( 0.95, 0.95, 0.95 ) },
    Parameter { name: "shininess"; value: 150.0                           }
]

techniques: [
    Technique {
        graphicsApiFilter {
            api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
            profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
            majorVersion: 3
            minorVersion: 1
        }

        filterKeys: [ FilterKey { name: "renderingStyle"; value: "forward" } ]

        parameters: [
            Parameter { name: "light.position";  value: Qt.vector4d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) },
            Parameter { name: "light.intensity"; value: Qt.vector3d( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )      }
        ]

        renderPasses: [
            RenderPass {
                filterKeys: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "forward" } ]

                shaderProgram: ShaderProgram {
                    vertexShaderCode:   loadSource("qrc:/shaders/thermal.vert")
                    fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/thermal.frag")
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: where did you read that `glBlendFunc` is a function that can be used inside a fragment shader? Or did I misread that and you're calling it ouside of the shader?

Comment: Added shader code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the `glBlendFunc` directly is not possible in Qt3D. You need to set the `renderStates` property of your RenderPass. It should be something similar to this, depending on which blend function and other states you want to enable:

```
renderPasses: [
    RenderPass {
        filterKeys: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "forward" } ]
        renderStates: [
            CullFace { mode : CullFace.Back },       
            DepthTest { depthFunction: DepthTest.Less },         
            NoDepthMask { },         
            BlendEquationArguments {         
                sourceRgb: BlendEquationArguments.SourceAlpha        
                destinationRgb: BlendEquationArguments.OneMinusSourceAlpha       
            },
            BlendEquation {blendFunction: BlendEquation.Add}
        ]

        shaderProgram: ShaderProgram {
            vertexShaderCode:   loadSource("qrc:/shaders/thermal.vert")
            fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/thermal.frag")
        }
    }
]
```